# StackOverflowError occurs sporadically when -vm <path java.exe> is not passed along with .exe file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse RCP application which I'm running by passing some arguments to it. I'm invoking eclipse application from command line. I have also configured the `-vmargs` through eclipse.ini file. Here, I have set `-Xss2m`. When I invoke application from command line passing `.exe --args`, the `StackOverflowError` occurs sporadically.
But if I invoke the application by passing `.exe -vm <path java.exe> --args` then the `StackOverflowError` doesn't occur.
I'm running the application using java 11.
How `-vm <path java.exe>` is having impact on the the eclipse application and stack size `-Xss`?

**Additional information**

.log which is generated in .metadata is having the correct logs which shows `StackOverflowError` by eclipse based library which I am using in eclipse RCP. I have to use stack as `-Xss2m` for the eclipse based library to work without any `StackOverflowError` issue. But what is strange is, if I don't invoke the eclipse RCP without `-vm <path java.exe>` then the application fails with `StackOverflowError` sporadically. If I invoke eclipse RCP as `rcp.exe -vm <path java.exe> --args`, then it doesn't with fail any `StackOverflowError`. How -vm is having an impact on stack?

Stack trace from .log file

````
       at autosar40.adaptiveplatform.applicationdesign.diagnosticserviceneeds.DiagnosticserviceneedsPackage.<clinit>(DiagnosticserviceneedsPackage.java:78)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1042)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:186)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1105)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1086)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418)
       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:304)
       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)
       at autosar40.adaptiveplatform.applicationdesign.grantdesign.comgrant.impl.ComgrantPackageImpl.init(ComgrantPackageImpl.java:1773)
       at autosar40.adaptiveplatform.applicationdesign.grantdesign.comgrant.ComgrantPackage.<clinit>(ComgrantPackage.java:82)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1042)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:186)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1105)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1086)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418)
       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader$EPackageDescriptor.getEPackage(RegistryReader.java:304)
       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl.getEPackage(EPackageRegistryImpl.java:127)```
````

Comment: What is the stack trace? Can you debug eclipse using Eclipse PDE and reproduce it in there? Is it eclipse or an eclipse plugin?

Comment: It's a different eclipse based library which I'm using inside the eclipse application.

Comment: Attach with a profiler like visualvm to see what actually happens

Comment: I'm confused. You're talking about *running* a Java app yet also about starting Eclipse. Eclipse is for *developing* applications, not running them…

Comment: @g00se It is possible to write plug-ins for Eclipse which can be run as a standalone application using the Eclipse `-application` command line argument. I believe that is what is being done here.

Comment: Eclipse should be writing a .log file containing the stack trace in the .metadata of the workspace to app uses.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. I have developed an eclipse based application and exported it using product export option from .product file. I am running the exported application through command line using `sample.exe --args`

Comment: So an Eclipse RCP - unless you are specify -data @None that will still have a workspace with a .metadata directory and a .log file. What is in the .log file?

Comment: I just edited the post with additional information.

Comment: @greg-449 Any comments from your side?

Comment: Your edit really doesn't provide any new information. I believe if you don't specify the java path then the Eclipse startup code looks for the jvm dll rather than the java.exe, no idea why that would make a difference.